# Adding a point to ScreenSpaceLines3D results in NullReferenceException

Tags: wpf, 3d, nullreferenceexception, helix-3d-toolkit

I am using `SharpenLines3d` in my projects to draw lines to connect objects in my `Viewport3D`. Problem is, when I'm adding points to `ScreenSpaceLined3D`, the program crashes, like this:

[image]

It crashes not in these lines when I'm adding points to `ScreenSpaceLines3D`, so it's something inside the library, I guess.

Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX + 1; i++)
{
    ...

    var bounds = this.points[i].Bounds;

    var x = bounds.X + (bounds.SizeX / 2);
    var y = bounds.Y + (bounds.SizeY / 2);
    var z = bounds.Z + (bounds.SizeZ / 2);

    coords[i] = new Point3D(x, y, z);

    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        lines[i, j] = new ScreenSpaceLines3D();
        lines[i, j].Color = Colors.Red;
        lines[i, j].Thickness = 6;

        lines[i, j].Points.Add(coords[i]);
        lines[i, j].Points.Add(coords[j]);
    }

}
```

I am sure that I am not passing `null` as argument to `Add` function (I tried to replace my `Add` line with this: `lines[i, j].Points.Add(new Point3D(0, 0, 0));`, and it still didn't work).

And I commented out all code that uses `lines` variable, so this variable is used only when a bunch of new `ScreenSpaceLines3D` is created. But my program crashes not on initializing.

When I comment out 2 strings of code where I'm adding points to lines, program starts working okay, but when I'm adding it again, result is as in screenshot.

How to deal with it?

UPD: Adding `MainViewPort.Children.Add(lines[i, j]);` after adding points made it work. It is getting more and more strage.

Comment: How do you declare and initialize the lines variable? Are you sure lines[i, j] is not null? Can you paste the stack trace?

Comment: @LajosArpad I declared lines that way: `ScreenSpaceLines3D[,] lines = new ScreenSpaceLines3D[MAX + 1, MAX + 1];`

Comment: @LajosArpad whoops, they are not null, my mistake, I was looking at the wrong place.

Comment: @LajosArpad and according to the stacktrace, it crashes at the `_3DTools.MathUtils.TryWorldToCameraTransform(Viewport3DVisual visual, Boolean& success)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow adding `MainViewPort.Children.Add(lines[i, j]);` solved the problem. Without it, program crashes, but with it, everything works okay.

I don't know how this works but this is it.